# Pd['Column1] > Pd['Column2'] Key Error: 0

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-datareader

I am trying to write a function that loops through a pandas dataframe and compares if column1 > column2, if so appends 1 to a list, which is then returned.

Importing finance data from yahoo finance, calculating 2 Std and assigning to column upper and lower, and the moving average.

```
    import pandas as pd 
    import pandas_datareader as web
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    %matplotlib inline
    from datetime import datetime
    import numpy as np

    end = datetime(2021, 1, 16)
    start = datetime(2020 , 1, 16)

    symbols = ['ETH-USD']
    stock_df = web.get_data_yahoo(symbols, start, end)
    period = 20
    # Simple Moving Average
    stock_df['SMA'] = stock_df['Close'].rolling(window=period).mean()
    # Standard deviation
    stock_df['STD'] = stock_df['Close'].rolling(window=period).std() 
    # Upper Bollinger Band
    stock_df['Upper'] = stock_df['SMA'] + (stock_df['STD'] * 2)
    # Lower Bollinger Band
    stock_df['Lower'] = stock_df['SMA'] - (stock_df['STD'] * 2)
    # List of columns
    column_list = ['Close', 'SMA', 'Upper', 'Lower']
    stock_df[column_list].plot(figsize=(12.2,6.4)) #Plot the data
    plt.title('ETH-USD')
    plt.ylabel('USD Price ($)')
    plt.show();

    #Create a new data frame, Period for calculation, removes NAN's
    bolldf = stock_df[period-1:]
    #Show the new data frame
    bolldf
```

Function, Loop through column rows and compare, append df['Close'][0] to buy/sell signal if condition is met.

---

```
    def signal(df):
         buy_signal = []
         sell_signal = [] 

         for i in range(len(df['Close'])):
            if df['Close'][i] > df['Upper'][i]:
               buy_signal.append(1)
         return buy_signal

    buy_signal = signal(bolldf)

    buy_signal
```

---

Info about the Error:

KeyError: 0

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
---> 12 buy_signal = greaterthan(stock_df)

KeyError: 0

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
11
---> 12 buy_signal = greaterthan(stock_df)
13

----> 8         if bolldf['Close'][i] > bolldf['Open'][i]:

KeyError: 0

When i attempt this function on the columns df['Upper'] > df['Lower], or df['SMA'] < df['Lower'] for example it works as expected, its only when using the columns from the original data that it does not work.

Any help would be amazing. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is a multi-index, the columns must also be specified in the multi-index format. You can check the contents of the columns with `bolldf.columns`, and you can get them by modifying as follows.

```
bolldf.columns
MultiIndex([('Adj Close', 'ETH-USD'),
            (    'Close', 'ETH-USD'),
            (     'High', 'ETH-USD'),
            (      'Low', 'ETH-USD'),
            (     'Open', 'ETH-USD'),
            (   'Volume', 'ETH-USD'),
            (      'SMA',        ''),
            (      'STD',        ''),
            (    'Upper',        ''),
            (    'Lower',        '')],
           names=['Attributes', 'Symbols'])

def signal(df):
    buy_signal = []
    sell_signal = []    
    for i in range(len(df[('Close','ETH-USD')])):
        if df[('Close','ETH-USD')][i] > df[('Upper','')][i]:
            buy_signal.append(1)
    return buy_signal

buy_signal = signal(bolldf)
```